# Matlab: 'Matrix dimensions must agree' less than operator (<)?

Tags: matlab

A quick question because i fear there may already be an answer (although i cant find it)

i am getting the error: Matrix dimensions must agree.

because i am useing '<'

now with all the other operators there is a way around this either by putting '.' infront or by using a different formula. So what do people do about the less than operator????
i don't see why the greater than or equal to (>=) works but yet less than does not!?

am i being stupid and missed something really obvious??

code snippet
matrix 1 represents an array of 16 numbers
matrix 2 can represents anywhere between 10 and 20 numbers

idx = (matrix2 >= matrix1 * 0.1 & matrix2 < matrix1 * 1.5);

any help guidance or advice on the topic would be much appreciated! thank you!

EDIT
i know the matrices are different sizes but is there a way to use less then with different size arrays? as im not bothered about the size of the array but the numbers within

Comment: probably the problem is in the size of the matrixes, of course. But without knowing the data its nto posible to help!

Comment: If `matrix1` and `matrix2` are not scalars, they _must_ have the same dimensions. You cannot use [relational operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-38145) otherwise.

Comment: Note that you will also get this error if the matrices are the same size, except transposed, e.g. if they are two vectors of the same length but one is a row vector and the other is a column vector.

Comment: i said the size of the matrices are 
matrix1 is 16
matrix2 is 10
(but matrix2 can also be between 10 and 20 so always goignt o be a different size)

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be, if the inputs have different sizes?

Comment: make comparisons on the items it can and class the rest as 0?

Comment: You should have written concrete example that bothers you...

Comment: @Tom then pad the shorter vector with `inf` or `-inf`, depending on which outcome you want to produce for "missing values"...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare parts of matrices, like `M(1:3,10:12)>A(5:7,1:3)`, you, probably, have to use the function `squeeze()`:

```
squeeze(M(1:3,10:12))>squeeze(A(5:7,1:3))
```

This function remotes singleton dimensions and everything works fine after.